# Question about intersection/union of a set and its complement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was answering this multiple choice question from this website [examtimequiz.com/maths-mcq-on-sets](http://examtimequiz.com/maths-mcq-on-sets):

> If $A$ is any set, then
>
> 1. $A \cup A' = U$
> 2. None of these
> 3. $A \cap A' = U$
> 4. $A \cup A' = \emptyset$

I answered (1), but apparently the correct answer is (3). Why?

And is the empty (null) set finite or infinite?

Comment: What is $\, A'$?  What is $\, U$?  For your other question, the empty set is a finite set since it has no elements.

Comment: actually I don't know what the question really mean I took it from this website http://examtimequiz.com/maths-mcq-on-sets/

Comment: but I think it means that the intersection of set A and A-prime = the universal set ... but I'm not really sure =)

Comment: Oh ok.  For me, it is impossible to know how to answer this question without knowing what $\, A'$ and $U$ are, and they could mean anything.  I checked out the website you gave and it didn't help me figure out what they mean.  Hopefully someone else can help you.

Comment: That site is garbage! Whoever wrote that quiz is poor at (a) English, (b) Maths, (c) Choosing HTML characters, (d) All of the above. Answer **d**.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a mistake. We can define $A'$ as $U \setminus A$. Also $A \subseteq U$.

Therefore $A \cup (U \setminus A) = U$ (which would be quite simple for show).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that $A'$ = the complement of set $A$, and that $U$ = the universal set. The red part is the set $A$, and $A'$ is everything in the white. The set $U$ is everything, so the red part + the white part. That makes $A \cup  A' = U$. So there was a mistake in the question and your answer is correct.

[image: Set Theory]